# Type of bit shift used by sha256

Tags: bitwise-operators, bit-shift, pseudocode, sha256

I was reading the pseudocode of sha256 on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2 . In the pseudocode , there is the right shift operation , but there is no saying what kind of bit shift are used in the pseudocode (arithmetic shift, logical shift, or circular shift).

Which type of bit shift is used by sha256 ?

I'm sorry if this looks like a beginner question , but i haven't found the answer anywhere.

Comment: nevermind , i found the answer , it was logical shift https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/57763/in-a-very-simplistic-and-step-by-step-example-how-do-i-get-the-w-values-for-s

Answer (score 1):

That is a good question and maybe the wiki should be updated to be more precise.
Having said that , the answer is the **logical right-shift** because it  inserts value 0 bits into the most significant bit and that's what happens in SHA-256.
The ambiguity is between arithmetic shift and logical shift though. the circular shift is for rotation